# Using != in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have table `Jobs`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Jobs]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ClientId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [JobType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Priority] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Done] [smallint] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And have record in it:

```
Id  ClientId    JobType Priority    Done
-----------------------------------------
1   41          1       1           NULL
```

Why does the query

```
SELECT JobType 
FROM Jobs 
WHERE Done != 1 
  AND ClientId = 41
```

return nothing?

Comment: Use `where Done is NULL`

Comment: You could try `WHERE ISNULL(Done, 0) != 1 AND ClientId = 41`. `NULL` is a bit of a tricky business in SQL .... you can't compare to it using normal comparison operators - only `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` will work

Comment: @marc_s: agreed that there is probably no index on `Done`, but since ISNULL prevents most optimisation by the DB engine, I would always avoid this when the expression is to be applied a criteria.

Comment: @iDevlop: agreed - but here, maybe that is what's needed, if one cannot just use `Done IS NOT NULL` or such....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `NULL` values is unknown values.

You have to use `NULL` and `NOT NULL` predicate to compare nullable values. This should work:

```
SELECT JobType 
from Jobs 
where (Done != 1 OR Done IS NULL) 
 and ClientId=41
```

Comment: But Done might be NULL and "0" (and maybe any other value) and I need exact !=1

Comment: @vico - See my updated aswer, use `(Done != 1 OR Done IS NULL) `

Answer (score 1):

In `SQL` `null <> null`.
   ISNULL use specified value(0) here, when Done is null.

```
SELECT JobType FROM Jobs 
WHERE ISNULL(Done, 0) <> 1 AND ClientId = 41
```

Answer (score 0):

NULL is not having any typ. As nothing is nothing. So you cannot compare something to NULL. Even `NULL = NULL` will return FALSE on most DBMS (I know there are some outside, doing it differently). To prevent this, there are constructs like `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NUL`L you can use e.g. inside your where clause.. Based on that, your query should look like something like:

```
SELECT "JobType" FROM "Jobs" WHERE "Done" IS NULL
```

If `Done` can have multiple values, you can use maybe something like

```
SELECT "JobType" 
FROM "Jobs" 
WHERE
   "Done" IS NULL OR
   "Done" <> 1
```

Also even `!=` works, `<>` is the more SQL-way IMHO to say unequal.